# A good fast way to redefine the structure of an array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I have an array looking like this:

```
    Array (
       [0] => Array
          (
              [id] => 1
              [day] => 12
              [month] => 10
              [year] => 2014
              [event_title] => numbwe1
              [event] => trip to this place unknown
          )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [day] => 16
            [month] => 10
            [year] => 2014
            [event_title] => number2
            [event] => trip to this other place unknown
        )
    )
```

And i would like to have it looking something like this

```
Array (
    [2014] => Array (
        [10] => Array (
            [1] => Array(
                [0] => Array(
                [event_title] = numbwe1
                [event] = trip to this place unknown
                )
            )

            [2] => Array(
                [0] => Array(
                [event_title] = number2
                [event] = trip to this other place unknown
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I don't know if it is because it is late, or if it is complicated, but i cannot get my head around it. Anyone got any ideas.

The purpose is that i will want to be able to pick all events based by year => month => date =>

Eg.
$events[2014] gives all events this year.

$events[2014][11] gives all events this month.

$events[2014][11][13] gives all events this day.

Alternative solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $a) {
    $year = $a['year'];
    $month = $a['month'];
    $day = $a['day'];
    if (!isset($newArray[$year])) $newArray[$year] = array();
    if (!isset($newArray[$year][$month])) $newArray[$year][$month] = array();
    if (!isset($newArray[$year][$month][$day])) $newArray[$year][$month][$day] = array();
    $newArray[$year][$month][$day][] = $a; // No sense stripping out useful information
}
```

Comment: ofcause, the simple solution, i have been staring blind on this one for hours, you win over Jonathan with 16 seconds. So you get the extra points.

Comment: ps. you missed a ) in line 6 and [] on line 11 except from that it worked like a charm. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Magic-Mouse Thanks, I've edited - sorry about the typos - it's what I get for being 16 seconds faster haha. Also thanks for catching that rather than doing the typical copy/paste and complaining the code doesn't work without understanding it ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should probably work. Warning:UNTESTED

```
function createDateSortableArray($array) {
    $sortableArray = [];
    foreach ($array as entry) {
        $year = $entry['year'];
        $month = $entry['month'];
        $daty = $entry['day'];
        if (!isset($sortableArray[$year])) {
            $sorableArray[$year] = [];
        }

        if (!isset($sortableArray[$year][$month])) {
            $sortableArray[$year][$month] = [];
        }

        if (!isset($sortableArray[$year][$month][$day]) {
            $sortableArray[$year][$month][$day] = [];
        }

        $sortableArray[$year][$month][$day][] = array(
            'event_title' => $entry['event_title'],
            'event' => $entry['event']
        );
    }

    return $sortableArray;
}
```